# How can I call filter once when I need to filter multiple things at the same time?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am using lodash to perform some filtering.

I have this functions:

```
filterByCardinalPoint = (key, value) => {
    const { passengersData } = this.props;
    console.log('passengersData', passengersData);
    return filter(passengersData, [key, value]);
  };

  callFilter = () => {
    passengersGoingNorth = this.filterByCardinalPoint('cardinalpoint', 'N')
      .length;
    passengersGoingSouth = this.filterByCardinalPoint('cardinalpoint', 'S')
      .length;
    passengersGoingWest = this.filterByCardinalPoint('cardinalpoint', 'W')
      .length;
    passengersGoingEast = this.filterByCardinalPoint('cardinalpoint', 'E')
      .length;
  };
```

And I am calling `callFilter` in the render method. This function is called around 8 times. How can I optimize it so that is call once?

Comment: I think you are looking for lodash's [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) functionality...

Comment: This may help: [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: How can I use that @gaetanoM

Comment: **filterByCardinalPoint** can accept an array of values as second arg and return an array or result....

Comment: @gaetanoM can you please a code sample so I can adapt it to my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need the amount of people going in each direction, you can use [`_.countBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#countBy) with [`_.property()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#property) as the iteratee. Destructure the result object to assign the numbers to the variables.

**Example:**

```js
const { countBy, property } = _;

let passengersGoingNorth, passengersGoingSouth, passengersGoingWest, passengersGoingEast;

const passengersData = [{ cardinalpoint: 'N' }, { cardinalpoint: 'N' }, { cardinalpoint: 'S' }, { cardinalpoint: 'N' }, { cardinalpoint: 'E' }];

({
  N: passengersGoingNorth = 0,
  S: passengersGoingSouth = 0,
  W: passengersGoingWest = 0,
  E: passengersGoingEast = 0
} = countBy(passengersData, property('cardinalpoint')));

console.log(passengersGoingNorth, passengersGoingSouth, passengersGoingWest, passengersGoingEast); // 3, 1, 0, 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It claims that `passengersGoingX` variables are already declare in the upper scope.

Comment: `SyntaxError: /PassengersCircle.js: You're trying to assign to a parenthesized expression, eg. instead of `({a}) = 0` use `({a} = 0)` (67:5)

  65 |     // ).length;
  66 | 
> 67 |     ({
     |      ^
  68 |       N: passengersGoingNorth,
  69 |       S: passengersGoingSouth,
  70 |       W: passengersGoingWest,`

Comment: Updated with a working example. Nothing but the defaults changed in the code itself. Your error is because the parentheses are in the wrong place - instead of ({a}) = 0` use ({a} = 0)

Comment: Plus that property there is one more I need to filter: `[{ cardinalpoint: 'N', pickup: 0 }, { cardinalpoint: 'N', pickup: 1 }]` I need to get a new array of pickup with 1. Is that an option I can include there in that code?

Comment: This code is specific for the problem, you've presented in the question, and it doesn't filter anything - it counts it. Your 2nd question should probably use a standard filter.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I need to do the same, count. But separating the ones with pickup: 0 and pickup: 1

Comment: So use the same logic with `pickup` as the proeprty, and destructure 1 and 0 to variables.

Comment: I have 5 passengers with `pickup: 1`. If I do this: `({
      1: passengersGoingNorthPickup,
      1: passengersGoingSouthPickup,
      1: passengersGoingWestPickup,
      1: passengersGoingEastPickup,
    } = countBy(passengersData, property('pickup')));` it assign `5` to every variable and not separately.

Comment: You can't destructure the same value multiple times. Please open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe thats too oldschool, but what about a simple `for` loop:

```
 for(const { cardinalpoint } of passengersData) {
   if(cardinalpoint === "N")
    passengersGoingNorth++;
   if(cardinalpoint === "S")
    passengersGoingSouth++;
   if(cardinalpoint === "E")
    passengersGoingEast++;
   if(cardinalpoint === "W")
    passengersGoingWest++;
 }
```

If that is too repetitive, just use the direction as a lookup key:

```
 const directions = { N: 0, S: 0, W: 0, E: 0 };
 for(const passenger of passengersData)
   directions[ passenger.cardinalpoint ]++;
```

Then you can get the passengers going south as `directions.S`.