# How can I destructure an Array to get the length of certain values inside of it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am trying to count on some arrays/objects using lodash.
I need to count the length of arrays which has the same cardinal point. I am using lodash `countBy` and `property`.

I am doing it like this:

```
let passengersGoingNorth = 0;
let passengersGoingEast = 0;
let passengersGoingSouth = 0;
let passengersGoingWest = 0;
...

   ({
      N: passengersGoingNorth,
      S: passengersGoingSouth,
      W: passengersGoingWest,
      E: passengersGoingEast,
    } = countBy(passengersData, property('cardinalpoint')));
```

And it returns the length for every element with the same cardinal point. Fir example `N` returns `2`.

Now, I need to do the same with a property named `pickup` which only comes with `0` and `1`. But I am unable to work on the proper logic to get it done:

```
let passengersGoingNorthPickup = 0;
let passengersGoingEastPickup = 0;
let passengersGoingSouthPickup = 0;
let passengersGoingWestPickup = 0;

   ({
      1: passengersGoingNorthPickup,
      passengersGoingSouthPickup,
      passengersGoingWestPickup,
      passengersGoingEastPickup,
    } = countBy(passengersData, property('pickup')));
```

I have 5 elements in total which comes `pickup: 1` and the way I am doing it above isn't working. 
In the object.

This is how the array comes:

```
[
{
  "cardinalpoint": "E"
  "pickup": 1,,
  "id": 6,
  "phone": "99998888",
},
{
  "cardinalpoint": "N"
  "pickup": 0,,
  "id": 1,
  "phone": "777777",
},
]
```

**UPDATE**
Before I did it like this and it works but the function gets call too many times but this is the idea:

```
passengersWithPickup = this.filterByCardinalPoint(
      passengersData,
      'pickup',
      1,
    );

    passengersGoingNorthPickup = this.filterByCardinalPoint(
      passengersWithPickup,
      'cardinalpoint',
      'N',
    ).length;
    passengersGoingSouthPickup = this.filterByCardinalPoint(
      passengersWithPickup,
      'cardinalpoint',
      'S',
    ).length;
    passengersGoingWestPickup = this.filterByCardinalPoint(
      passengersWithPickup,
      'cardinalpoint',
      'W',
    ).length;
    passengersGoingEastPickup = this.filterByCardinalPoint(
      passengersWithPickup,
      'cardinalpoint',
      'E',
    ).length;
```

So I am suppose to use the same logic for both things. But I need to get if pickup is 0 or 1 depending on the cardinal point. Like I need to know if the cardinal point is `N` if pickup contains `0` or `1`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose and expected result of `1` and `passengersGoingNorthPickup` at `1: passengersGoingNorthPickup`? Can you include the complete input array and expected result at the question? See https://stackoeverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Like if there are `3` passengers going to the `West` and 2 have `pickup: 1`, it is a count. So `passengersGoingNorthPickup === 2` @guest271314

Comment: Have little experience using lodash. Do you mean `cardinalPoint === "W" && pickup === 1`? Or only `pickup === 1`? Is the only expected result the `.length` of the objects in the input array which match the property name and value?

Comment: Um... How about reading the other answers to your previous question? Then you wouldn't have that problem at all. Or haven't you asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793253/how-can-i-call-filter-once-when-i-need-to-filter-multiple-things-at-the-same-tim/54793576#54793576)

Comment: Please post what `filterByCardinalPoint` does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the condition, so only items with truthy (not 0 in this case) `pickup` value will be counted under their `cardinalpoint` value.

If you'll look at the object before the destructuring, you'll see that items with `pickup` value 0, are counted under the 0 key.

```js
const { countBy, property } = _;

let passengersGoingNorth, passengersGoingSouth, passengersGoingWest, passengersGoingEast;

const passengersData = [{"cardinalpoint":"E","pickup":1,"id":6,"phone":"99998888"},{"cardinalpoint":"N","pickup":0,"id":1,"phone":"777777"}];

({
  N: passengersGoingNorth = 0,
  S: passengersGoingSouth = 0,
  W: passengersGoingWest = 0,
  E: passengersGoingEast = 0
} = countBy(passengersData, o => o.pickup && o.cardinalpoint ));

console.log(passengersGoingNorth, passengersGoingSouth, passengersGoingWest, passengersGoingEast); // 0, 0, 0, 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```